# Should I use a for loop for an SQL query or use a WHERE clause with multiple ORs and process the results

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, server

I have one MySQL table that I am using PHP to query data entries from multiple machines.  I need to summarize/analyze thousands of rows of data for each machine to output to a front-end results table.

I know that it is bad practice to include an sql query in a for loop, so currently I am using one query with 50+ OR statements in it.
i.e.

```
SELECT 'x','xx','xxx' 
  from table 
 WHERE machine_id = 'id1' 
    OR machine_id='id2' 
    OR...etc
```

Processing and sorting these result rows puts a lot of load on the server and takes ~ 10 seconds. Using a for loop also takes a long time, but is cleaner and easier to understand when other coders are reading it.

1)Is there a better way to query one table for multiple machines that each have thousands of rows?

2)Should I use the for loop because its easier to read/understand what is going on with the queries?

3)Another One: I've thought about running a cron and preprocessing these results every hour so the front end can just grab the pre-processed results, so I may go with that, but I would still like to know of a more efficient way to render this data to the front-end in real time.

Comment: We would normally use an `IN()` in this instance

Comment: That said, it's puzzling that your approach would take so long. Please provide the actual query, the CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, and the EXPLAIN

Comment: use IN()  ref: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx/